# How I can makea plot which I have customized in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot the following plot[image]

The x-axis ranges from 1 to 9, and the y-axis ranges from -0.5 to +0.5. I have also specified colours within the boxes

Comment: Nice job on the diagram but where is the [MCVE]? I would expect a data object created with R and a plot call of some sort from your choice among the three major plotting paradigms in R. You also need to define what is meant by "shadow black and white color". Perhaps you mean "grey"?

Comment: Many Thanks for your comment. Is it possible to produce hypothetical data to create the diagram? Yes, grey is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I created some reproducible data with Y factors and X values. You could define the correct and incorrect colors in a new column using `case_when`. To create bars use `geom_col` and `scale_fill_manual` to define the labels for your colors. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
# Data
df <- data.frame(Y = rep(c(0.3, -0.1, -0.3), each = 9),
                 X = rep(c(1:9), n = 3))

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  mutate(color = case_when(Y == 0.3 | Y == -0.3 ~ 'orange',
                           TRUE ~ 'grey')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = X, y = factor(Y), fill = color)) +
  geom_col(width = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual('', values = c('orange' = 'orange', 'grey' = 'grey'),
                    labels = c('Correct', 'Incorrect')) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(y = 'Y', x = '')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Update**

Slightly modify the data:

```r
df <- data.frame(Y = rep(c(0.45, 0.25, 0.05, -0.05, -0.25, -0.45), each = 9),
                 X = rep(c(1:9), n = 6))

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  mutate(color = case_when(Y %in% c(-0.45, 0.45, -0.25, 0.25) ~ 'orange',
                           TRUE ~ 'grey')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = X, y = factor(Y), fill = color)) +
  geom_col(width = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual('', values = c('orange' = 'orange', 'grey' = 'grey'),
                    labels = c('Correct', 'Incorrect')) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(y = 'Y', x = '')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Update to axis**

You can use the following code:

```r
df <- data.frame(Y = c(0.45, 0.25, 0.05, -0.05, -0.25, -0.45),
                 X = rep(9, n = 6))

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  mutate(color = case_when(Y %in% c(-0.45, 0.45, -0.25, 0.25) ~ 'orange',
                           TRUE ~ 'grey')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = X, y = factor(Y), fill = color)) +
  geom_col(width = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual('', values = c('orange' = 'orange', 'grey' = 'grey'),
                    labels = c('Correct', 'Incorrect')) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(y = 'Y', x = '') +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE, xlim = c(1, NA)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 9, by = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Very many thanks, I want to have the grey between -0.1 and 0.1. Can we do it?

Comment: @user330, Please check update above!

Comment: That's great! Is it possible to customise the X-axis based on my diagram, i.e., 1: 9? I am sorry to bother you.

Comment: This is really perfect, Thank you very much.  But I tried my best to see the -0.1 and +0.1 on the y-axixs for the grey area, but I  failed. Would it be possible for you to help me

Comment: Try add  `scale_y_discrete(labels = seq(-0.5, 0.5, by = 0.2))`.

Comment: I did already  but I don't get the grey area exactly between -0.1 and +0.1